# passing json array ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Trying to pass a array using ajax call.

```
info = [];
info[0] = 'hi';
info[1] = 'hello';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {info: info, "action": "getPatientRecords"},
    url: "/mobiledoc/jsp/ccmr/webPortal/carePlanning/servicePatientmilestoneModal.jsp",
    success: function(msg) {
        $('.answer').html(msg);
    }
});
```

However when i try to catch it on the server side using :
request.getParameter("info"); //Displays null**

Also, if i wish to send an array of arrays ? is it possible?

**I tried using serialize however my IE throws error that serialize : object doesnt support this property** i Did include jquery lib.

Comment: info['hi','hello']...use this insted of what you are using.thats an old wat to do go about arrays.

Comment: You need to stringify your json data.

Comment: JSON.stringify(info);

Comment: :if you got your answer,tick the answer you feel is correct.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `JSON.stringify(info)` to create a JSON representation of the object/array (including an array of arrays).  On the server side you should be able to get the string via `getParameter` and then unserialize it from JSON to create constructs JSP can use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,It is Possible to send arrays.

```
var info_to_send = ['hi','hello'];

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {info: info_to_send, "action": "getPatientRecords"},
    url: "/mobiledoc/jsp/ccmr/webPortal/carePlanning/servicePatientmilestoneModal.jsp",
    success: function(msg) {
        $('.answer').html(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why didn't you just use: `var info = ['hi','hello'];`?

Comment: Its displaying null at server side. System.out.println(request.getParameter("info")); //NULL

Comment: @MESSIAH (; Good Job.

Answer (score 1):

You can only provide strings in a request url.

You could encode the array like so:

```
info = JSON.stringify(info); 
// results in "['hi', 'hello']"
```

Then send it to the server, also JSON parse on the server.

You will need to go to http://www.json.org/ to get a Java implementation of JSON parsing.